# Zoom and Fade out Effect on Text with the Text visible on background

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

> I need to zoom and fade out a text, but the text must still be visible
>   in the background with its actual size.
>
> [Here is the fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Sanal_5/rLbrLxzf/3/) which I have done so far which works but
>   not perfect.

I am using two separate labels with `class='overlap'` to get the desired effect i want. I want to do this with a single label and not use two labels with same data on them. if this can't be fixed, is there any plugins which I can use to get this effect, that would be helpful.

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://jsfiddle.net/rLbrLxzf/4/

Comment: You can also use [animate css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) for making transitions.

Comment: @ProgrammerV5 no that's not it sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a pseudo element and [CSS Attr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/attr), and then toggle a class on the label

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".temp").change(function() {
    $('.zoom').attr('data-text', $('.temp').val());
    $(".zoom").addClass('flash');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".zoom").removeClass('flash');
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```css
.zoom {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.zoom::before {
  content: attr(data-text);
}
.zoom::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.zoom.flash::after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  transition: 1s ease;
  transform: scale(2);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class='zoom'></label>

<label>Enter some text and remove focus</label>
<input class='temp' type="text">
```

Comment: Thanks or the quick reply.